# Check if environment variable has been set in Ant script

Tags: java, ant

What is the most efficient way of checking if an environment variable has been set prior to executing the rest of an Ant script?

Let's say my Ant script requires the environment variable "FOO" to be set.  I got the following to work, but I was wondering whether there was a less convulated way of achieving the same result:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="env.FOO" value=""/>

<target name="my-target">
    <condition property="foo.found">
        <not>
            <equals arg1="${env.FOO}" arg2=""/>
        </not>
    </condition>
    <fail unless="foo.found" message="FOO not set."/>
    <!-- do stuff here that uses the FOO environment variable -->
</target>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Isn't this as simple as:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<fail unless="env.FOO" message="FOO not set."/>
```

Comment: Yes you're right!  I only just noticed that I had ${env.FOO} passed to the unless attribute! (i.e. I had the dollar and curly braces).  In fact, the reason why I had that issue was that I actually tried to set a property with the name "bar" to be ${env.FOO} and then use the property "bar" in the unless part.  Not sure how I'd keep the "bar" property if I wanted to.

Answer (score 8):

and the other thing you can do (additional to David's) is use

```
<isset property="env.Foo"/> instead of <equals />
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Ant 1.9.2. This target does not fail, even if FOO is not set: `<target name="paul"> <fail message="FOO not set.">  <condition> <isset property="env.FOO"/>
 </condition> </fail> </target>`
`

Answer (score 1):

Close:

```
<fail message="FOO not set.">
    <condition>
        <isset property="env.FOO"/>
    </condition>
</fail>
```

This won't fail if $FOO was set, but is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten it a bit by using an embedded `<condition>` inside `<fail>`.

```
<property environment="env"/>
<fail message="FOO not set.">
    <condition>
        <isset property="${env.FOO}"/>
    </condition>
</fail>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="test.home.0" value="${env.TEST_HOME}"/>
<condition property="test.home" value="TO_BE_REPLACED">
  <equals arg1="${test.home.0}" arg2="\${env.TEST_HOME}"/>
</condition>
<property name="test.home" value="${env.TEST_HOME}"/>

<target name="test">
  <echo>TEST_HOME: ${test.home}</echo>
</target>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I came up with, using the isset property to check for a enviro variable that is only present on Unix.  set.properties is the first target to kick this off.

```
<property environment="env" />        

<target name="init" depends="set.properties" />

    <!--  Do init stuff....  -->
    </target>

    <!-- Other target stuff.....  -->

<!--
        Target: set.properties
--> 
<target name="set.properties"       
 description="Initializes Build Script, checks displays properties"
     depends="cond.hostname.exist,cond.hostname.not.exist">
</target>

<!--
        Target: check.cond HostName is Present
-->     
<target name="cond.check">
    <condition property="cond-is-true">
            <isset property="env.HOSTNAME"/>
    </condition>
</target>   

<!--
        Target: cond.hostname.exist
-->         
<target name="cond.hostname.exist" depends="cond.check" if="cond-is-true">
    <property name="targetboxname"  value="${env.HOSTNAME}" />
</target>   

<!--
        Target: cond.hostname.not.exist
-->             
<target name="cond.hostname.not.exist" depends="cond.check" unless="cond-is-true">
    <property name="targetboxname"  value="${env.COMPUTERNAME}" />
</target>   

    <!-- Then later on....  -->
    <echo>ComputerName/HostName:  ${targetboxname}  </echo>
```